# @Component with request scope attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, scope, components, spring-annotations

I have a class in my SpringBoot project with `@Component`. By default, the Scope of this is singleton and it's OK.
But now I need an object, with request scope, that will be used in many methods of this Component class. The only way to do this is passing this object as parameter in all methods? Or can I, for example, declare a `@RequestScope` attribute in a singleton, or something like that?

----EDIT

An example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    private MyBC myBC;

    private MyClass myObject;

    public method1(MyClass param) {
        myObject = param;
        method2();
    }

    public method2() {
        System.out.println(myObject);
    }
}
```

My problem is: in this code, `myObject` is a singleton. Depending on concurrency, I will have problems with different requests, one will affect the other in `method2()`. I need `myObject` to be Request Scoped.

Comment: How do you gain data for `myObject`, do you extract it from `RequestContext`?

Comment: @birca123 In fact, my app starts with an IBMMQ message. But I think yes, could be from a `ResquestContext`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `MyClass` as a `@RequestScope` component as follows:

```java
@Component
@RequestScope
public class MyClass {

  private Object data;

  public MyClass(HttpServletRequest request) {
    data = //extract data from the request
  }

  public Object getData() {
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then you inject it like any other bean and don't have to pass the `MyClass` parameter to each method. The component is instantiated by each request only if you access it, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886843/is-component-defined-with-request-scope-lazy-loaded).

Be aware that the request scope is not available outside a thread attached to a request. If you access it from a non-request-bound thread the following exception will be thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found

Comment: Yeah, I've already made that, but I received exactly that error  `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.myClass': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread?`

Comment: This means you're not executing those methods from the `Controller` class, is that right? If some kind of message listeners executes them there is no `RequestContext`, therefore `@RequestScope` can't be used in that case.

Comment: It's from IBMMQ consumer (JMS), I think cant use @RequestScope

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem clean to me:

Firstly, let's call your `@Component` class as a `Component`.

---

Do you want to use another singleton object ( call it `OtherS`) *inside* your `Component`'s methods?

Use `Lombok`'s `RequiredArgsConstructor` with `private static final OtherS otherSingleton`, then you can use it inside your `Component`, in any methods.

---

### OR

---

Do you want to use `Component`'s object in other methods of other class?

You can inverse previous block and make same thing with `Component` (as with `OtherS` earlier). As you declare it as a `Bean` inside another `Bean` using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` it will not be `null` and will be used as a `Singleton` class attribute (so you can access it with `this`-kw).

Comment: Hello @p0var, thanks for the answer. I edit the original question to be more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Lazy` annotation.

> @Lazy with @Bean (or @Lazy with @Component): don't load
> eagerly during application start up, until it's used in the
> application
>
> @Lazy with @Autowired : don't load during outer class initialization,
> until it's first used by the application.

When started context, you musnt to load `MyReqBean`.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xyz")
public class MyConfig {

    private final MyBC myBC;

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @RequestScope //define req bean.
    public MyReqBean myReqBean() {
        return new MyReqBean(myBC);
    }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyReqBean {
    
    private final MyBC myBC; //singleton bean

    public method2() {
        System.out.println(myBC.getX());
    }
}
```

`MyReqBean` is created on each request and will be destroyed when the request ends.